# setInterval does not work properly in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, setinterval

I got a problem with setInterval in ReactJS (particularly Functional Component). I want to enable autoplay slider (it means value in Slider Bar will be increased after a period of time). This function will be triggered when I click a button. But I don't know exactly how setInterval works with setValue. The console log just returns the initial value (does not change) (console.log function was called in a callback function of setInterval).

My code is below:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(10);
const [playable, setPlayable] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    if (playable === true) {
        console.log("Trigger");
        const intervalId = setInterval(increaseValue, 1000);
        return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
    }
}, [playable]);

const increaseValue = () => {
    console.log(value);
    setValue(value + 1);
};

const autoPlay = () => {
    setPlayable(true); 
};


return (
    <div>
        <div style={{"width": "800px"}}>
            <Slider
                value={value}
                step={1}
                valueLabelDisplay="on"
                getAriaValueText={valueText}
                marks={marks}
                onChange={handleChange}
                min={0}
                max={100}
            />
        </div> 
        <button onClick={autoPlay}>Play</button>
    </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I think you need to pass `increaseValue` function into useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (playable === true) {
        console.log("Trigger");
        const intervalId = setInterval(increaseValue, 1000);
        return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
    }
}, [playable, increaseValue]);
```

Comment: I have tested it. It didn't work. The console logs are just 10 (the initial value)

Comment: It works. Just bringing increaseValue function above useEffect and do your instruction. Can you explain to me what happened and why do I add increaseMethod to the second param of useEffect? Thank a lot.

Comment: So, I think you need also useCallback. I tried to write this code here. You can see https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-silence-vy2d7?file=/src/App.js

Comment: You are welcome, but If you mark my answer as Answer. It will be the best thanks for me)